# Using STUFF on joined tables and replacing NULL values with a constant string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the results of a joined table for this, with the code below. Is it possible to join together the results of a query with a join while at the same time, replacing NULL values? I tried the code below but I can't get them to work with the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
    tblAdmission.AdmissionID
    , CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) [Name]
    , Birthdate
    , AdmissionDate
    , Ward
    , Service
    , Outcome
    , ISNULL(
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + OrganismName
            FROM tblOrganism
            WHERE tblOrganism.OrganismID = tblHAIFile.OrganismID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
        , 'No Isolate Found') [Isolated Organisms]
FROM
    tblAdmission
INNER JOIN tblPatient ON tblAdmission.PatientID = tblPatient.PatientID
INNER JOIN tblHAIFile ON tblAdmission.AdmissionID = tblHAIFile.AdmissionID
LEFT JOIN tblOrganism ON tblHAIFile.OrganismID = tblOrganism.OrganismID

GROUP BY
    tblAdmission.AdmissionID, CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName),
    Birthdate, AdmissionDate, Ward, Service, Outcome, tblHAIFile.OrganismID
```

This is the current output of the query above, and the one I'm trying to create: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InnlX.jpg

Comment: you need to use the "FOR XML PATH" on the final result set of your main query, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your main query in a CTE, but exclude the `FOR XML PATH` part,
then use a second CTE to Split/Concat your column `IsolatesFound`.
the final query will be joining them both together by ID and use distinct

I used this data sample:

```
    ;WITH Tmp (ID, Name , BirthDate , AdmissionDate, Ward, Service, OutCome ,  IsolatesFound) as 
    (
    SELECT 4 , 'Hammer, Oliver' , CAST('1/21/1993' AS DATE) , CAST('5/1/1993' AS DATE) , 'Ward 9' , 'Gen Ped 1' , 'No Specified' , 'No Isolate Found'
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 10 , 'Hammer, Oliver' , CAST('1/22/2000' AS DATE) , CAST('2/28/2018' AS DATE) , 'NICU' , NULL , 'No Specified' , 'No Isolate Found'
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 10 , 'Hammer, Oliver' , CAST('1/22/2000' AS DATE) , CAST('2/28/2018' AS DATE) , 'NICU' , NULL , 'No Specified' , 'Something'
    )
    , Main (Id , [Isolated Organisms] ) as
    (
    SELECT Id , 
    STUFF(CAST((SELECT ','+ IsolatesFound 
            FROM Tmp a 
            WHERE a.ID = t.ID
            FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ) AS NVARCHAR(2000)),1,1,'') 
    FROM tmp t
    GROUP BY t.ID
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT  m.Id , t.BirthDate , t.AdmissionDate , t.Ward , t.Service , t.OutCome ,m.[Isolated Organisms] 
    FROM Main m
    JOIN Tmp t
    ON m.Id = t.ID
```

See the code the you can apply on your existing tables:

```
    ;WITH MainQuery as 
    (
    SELECT
        tblAdmission.AdmissionID
        , CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) [Name]
        , Birthdate
        , AdmissionDate
        , Ward
        , Service
        , Outcome
        , ISNULL(IsolatesFound, 'No Isolate Found') IsolatesFound

    FROM
        tblAdmission
    INNER JOIN tblPatient ON tblAdmission.PatientID = tblPatient.PatientID
    INNER JOIN tblHAIFile ON tblAdmission.AdmissionID = tblHAIFile.AdmissionID
    LEFT JOIN tblOrganism ON tblHAIFile.OrganismID = tblOrganism.OrganismID
    )
    , Split (AdmissionID  , [Isolated Organisms] ) as 
    (
    SELECT t.AdmissionID , 
    STUFF(CAST((SELECT ','+ IsolatesFound 
            FROM MainQuery a 
            WHERE a.AdmissionID= t.AdmissionID
            FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE ) AS NVARCHAR(2000)),1,1,'') 
    FROM MainQuery t
    GROUP BY t.AdmissionID
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT  m.AdmissionID, t.BirthDate , t.AdmissionDate , t.Ward , t.Service , t.OutCome ,m.[Isolated Organisms] 
    FROM Split m
    JOIN MainQuery t
    ON m.AdmissionID= t.AdmissionID
```

Comment: Thanks @hkravitz, this snippet worked! I've also added a couple more things to it to give the query more context. I have to admit, I consider myself a greenhorn in SQL so I've very little understanding as to how it worked. Do you mind adding comments to the snippet for context?

Comment: When you want to append data (denormalized) using the FOR XML PATH is one way to achieve that.In your case I used your main query and on it's result set you can apply a self join and apply the FOR XML PATH on the column you wish convert to a comma delimited list. There are many examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT . . .
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + COALESCE(o.OrganismName, 'No Isolate Found')
             FROM tblOrganism o
             WHERE o.OrganismID = tblHAIFile.OrganismID
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
           ) as [Isolated Organisms]
```

Also, I doubt you need `tblOrganism` in the outer query . . . and you may not need the `GROUP BY` as well:

```
SELECT . . .,
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + COALESCE(o.OrganismName, 'No Isolate Found')
             FROM tblOrganism o
             WHERE o.OrganismID = tblHAIFile.OrganismID
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
           ) as [Isolated Organisms]
FROM tblAdmission a INNER JOIN
     tblPatient p
     ON a.PatientID = p.PatientID;
```

In general, you don't want the table where you are gathering the items in the string in the outer `FROM`.

Also, this method is based on XML.  The `STUFF()` is not at all required for it.  The `STUFF()` is only removing the first comma -- a very unimportant part of the operation.

Comment: Hi Gordon, appreciate the help! I tried out the code however, it seemed to take out the condition where there is both 'no isolate found' and where an isolate was found (eg: row 2 in the output). In this context, I don't think a CASE sequence would work since it just chooses whether there is or there is no isolate, and it will only stuff together the ones that do, and not the ones that do and don't have any isolate.

Comment: @RemiDarren . . . Oh, that is simpler than the way I understood the question.